# Making the menubar and logo follow the webpage when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my logo and manu bar to follow my page as i scroll down the page,

Currently this is what i have.

CSS is;

```
html,body {
background-image:url(../img/background.png);
background-size:cover;
background:fixed;
}


#bar {  
margin-top:55px;
width: 1920px center;
height: 30px;
background: #2E2E2E;
border: 3.2px groove #FFD700;  
}
#logo { 
position:absolute;
background-image:url(../img/LOGO1.png);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
top:0px;
margin: 0 auto;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}
#middle
{
height:10000px;
}
```

and for HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
</div>
<div id="bar">
</div>
<div id="middle">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So please what would i need to change to make both 'bar' and 'logo' follow my scroll.

thankyou for you help

Comment: You would add `position:fixed` to the elements

Comment: Thanks, i just added that to both bar and logo but it makes the bar small and to the left,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle with how I would do it...

http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqhw/

I've wrapped both elements in a div, gave it `position:fixed` and `width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

You could try nesting logo and bar within another div and then setting `position:fixed` on the enclosing div so your HTML would look something like:

```
<div id="fixed_bar" style="position:fixed;">
  <div id="logo"/>
  <div id="bar"/>
</div>
<div id="middle">
</div>
```

Or you could add the enclosing div as above but define the style for it in the CSS:

```
#fixed_bar
{
  position:fixed;
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<div id="fixed_bar">
  <div id="logo"/>
  <div id="bar"/>
</div>
<div id="middle">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a div to wrap your logo and bar and use CSS to set the position to fixed.

The CSS:

```
#nav-fixed {
    position:fixed;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="nav-fixed">

    <div id="logo">
    </div>

    <div id="bar">
    </div>

</div>
```